# unidentified bug in a try catch javascript statement

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to implement a (very) simple try{}catch{} block that looks like this:

```
try{
    var invoice = parseInt(localStorage[0]);
    if(invoice == NaN)
       throw "invoice not a number";
    localStorage[invoice] = Ticket;
    console.log("localStorage["+invoice+'] : '+localStorage[invoice]);
   }
   catch (e){
      console.log(e);
      this.test();
   }
```

What I do is manually clear localStorage with another function, thereby setting localStorage[0] to undefined.  When I parseInt(localStorage[0]), it returns NaN, and stores it into invoice.  I used the double equals conditional on invoice and NaN so, just in case, it should be true even if NaN is a string (which it shouldn't be).

My question is:  Why, when I say "throw..." does it not call the catch portion of the block?

When I run the following code, I get the following output in Chrome's console:

> localStorage[NaN] : [object Object]

it doesn't even run the catch block, and in fact, continues running the try block, even after it should have thrown the exception.

why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NaN` isin't equal to itself, use `isNaN`.

Comment: This behaviour is often, unfairly, the target of "wtf javascript!!!" comments. It is in fact defined in the IEEE-754 standard for floating point numbers, which Javascript implements.

Comment: yeah, really!  but thank goodness for isNaN.  our forefathers knew we would encounter this issue when they created that.  unfortunately, they didn't foresee that a person has to know that it exists for it to be of value to the person!